# Wordpress REST API Visual Composer Shortcodes

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I am have a little bit of a hard time with the wordpress REST API outputting shortcode tags rendered from visual composer. The idea is to grab the API data and feed it into anoter website in realtime, but with the other website not being on the wordpress platform, the only way i can see around the problem is to strip the tags in the code on the receiving end.

Ideally i wanted to out put clean text, keep the html content (for the paragraphs to remain) but just strip the dreaded shortcodes generated by  visual composer. (please see screenshot below). Obviously i do not want to touch any core files.

[image: rendered content in REST API]

Comment: have you tried using the rendered content instead of the raw content?

Comment: I believe this is rendered and not the raw content ?? Unless i misunderstand the API functions properly ??

Comment: ah I see, shortcodes should be rendered in that field, but if visual composer shortcodes are not being rendered then that is a bug in visual composer

Comment: There's a solution for rendering shortcodes with visual composer [discussed here](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2578).

Comment: Thank you for the link, however the solution to modify core files seems to be the only answer given on any forum, which is always a bad idea (security vulnerabilities and it will reset the code on every update). I am starting to think the only solution is to either create a automated script in python to act as a bridge or just regex any shortcodes in code on the receiving end. Such a shame